# Error while trying to run Pharo for the first time

Tags: installation, smalltalk, pharo

I am trying to run Pharo on my system (Ubuntu 17.10 64bit).I followed the exact procedure as given in the book Pharo By Example.

I Went into the Pharo6.1-64 directory and ran the following command in the terminal

```
./pharo shared/pharo6.1-64.image
```

I expected this to open the Pharo window where I can write code but instead saw this error in the Terminal.

```
./pharo: line32: /home/user/pharo6.1-64/vm/pharo: No such file or directory.
```

Do I need to download any additional files ?
I downloaded the zip from [here](https://pharo.org/gnu-linux-installation-64) and it said just extract and run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the pharo.image and pharo.changes to the directory containing the pharo executable and from terminal run the command

```
Pharo_executable path_to_Pharo_image
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is something wrong with the file you downloaded. It does not seem to contain a vm. For now, try the other method mentioned in the book:

```
wget -O- get.pharo.org/50+vm | bash
```

Comment: At first this also didn't work but I managed to run the original one because of the error message I got while running this version(interesting isn't it), so thanks anyway.

Comment: @Daksh if you solved your problem it would be nice to write what you did as an answer. It could help others facing the same problem! Also if this A helped you you could upvote it, if not accept it.

Comment: Yeah, I posted what I did.